# API for getting names of nearby shops from GPS location on a smartphone

Tags: c#, java, javascript, ios, apache-flex

I am looking for an API which returns a list of nearby shop/cafe/business names (with coordinates would be great but not needed) within a given radius (or simply "nearby" if available) - from a given set of coordinates (which could be the current location).

I am undecided as to which platform to use (native Android or iOS or non-native AIR for example or Javascript/ajax on a webpage) and so welcome any known apis. I would only expect the api to work on web-enabled devices.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely, google has something of this sort, but you'll have to investigate google maps api to see the details. Google definitely supports this kind of search on their maps.google.com site, so they may also be providing API interface to do this programmatically.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#LocalSearch http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html#ReverseGeocoding some starting points though I've used neither in the context of a mobile browser so I'm not sure how it would play out.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Foursquare Venue Explore API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) in one of my last projects. Maybe it fits in your case.

Comment: This looks very good indeed...I'll leave the q unanswered for a bit to attract more solutions.